# Run a .exe file using Open SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, openssh

I am trying to run a .exe file on a remote Windows machine on an AWS instance using Open SSH but the .exe file does not seem to run. There is no error at all. The command I am using is

```
ssh -i <path to id_rsa> Administrator@<ip address> 'cmd.exe "<path to .exe>"'.
```

There is a brief pause when I run the command, seems as if *something* is happening but the .exe file is not running.

Comment: Try adding `-t` maybe? https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#t

Comment: @RaGe thanks but it did not work. Neither -t nor -T.